# Удаленное подключение к БД

Tags: c#, sql-server

Есть 2 пк. На одном установлен MSSQL, на другом стоит программа(написанная на C#) на котором нету MSSQL. Так вот вопрос как без установки на 2ой пк сервера подключится к бд. Вот в MySQL просто прописываешь, `ip-адрес` сервера и порт MySQL и кладешь рядом c приложением `DLL` и свободно можно подключиться. А вот как это у MSSQL реализовано не подскажите? 
И как тогда должна выглядеть строка подключения. У меня пока вот так, это если сервер и приложение на одном пк.

```
constr=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbtest1;Integrated 
Security=True;
```

Хотя удаленно со второго ПК через SQL manager  я могу подключится. Имя пк и порт в настройках 1433. И я вижу весь список БД на сервере.

Comment: `.` вот здесь `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` означает локалхост

Answer (score 2):

**Дано**

`ip-адрес` машины на кот. установлен `SQL Server`:  192.168.0.205

Имя пользователя: `sa`

Пароль пользователя: `123KUku`

Название базы: `AdventureWorks2017`

**Строка подключения** такая (др. параметры см.документацию)

```
Data Source=192.168.0.205;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2017;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=123KUku;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```